# SQL Query: Count Distinct with Condition

Tags: sql, hive, presto

This is my simplified table:

```
 is_clicked | direct_lead_id 
------------+----------------
 true       |        4074448 
 false      |        4074448 
 true       |        4074448
```

I would like to run a query on this to get a distinct count of the direct_lead_id when is_clicked = True. So the result of my query would be 1 in this case. If I added a line to the above table, let say:
true| 407449. 
Then I would want to get 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(distinct direct_lead_id ) 
from my_table
where is_clicked = true
```